# Convert or transpose excel report (horizontal) to tabular (vertical) format for importing

Tags: microsoft-excel, import, report, transpose

Have been trying to find a solution so i can import this data into my ERP
We get the report in a horizontal or report format (on the left) and manually enter into our system.  If we can convert into a vertical format (on the right) we can import it instead.
The columns would be STYLE   COLOR  SIZES   QTY

I found something close but i could not expand on it with my limited experience
([Convert multiple rows into single column based on values](https://superuser.com/questions/454344/convert-multiple-rows-into-single-column-based-on-values))

[image]

Comment: It looks like an Unpivot solution would work.  There are plenty of examples on both superuser and stackoverflow using VBA and/or Power Query.

Answer (score 1):

As Ron Rosenfeld suggested, you may use Power Query to transpose your data.

**Step 1:** Choose the data, right-click it > Get Data from Table/Range, do not tick the box of "My table has headers" > OK.

**Step 2:** Go to File tab > Reduce Rows group > Remove Duplicates. This action could remove some duplicated headers from data source.

[image]

**Step 3:** After Step 2, the data would be divided into some types with different sizes. On my sample, there are 2 types, then I go to left Queries panel, copy the table.

**Step 4:** Remove extra rows and keep one size type for each query. For my sample, I go to File tab > Reduce Rows group > Keep Rows > Keep Range of Rows. As there is an extra column, I delete it in X, XS siez query.

**Step 5:** Set the first row as headers for each query. Select columns of size,

[image]

**Step 6:** Then I do unpivot for each query. Go to Transform tab > Any Colum group > Unpivot Columns.

[image]

[image]

**Step 7:** Rename the column names, then click File tab > Combine group > Append Queries.

[image]

**Steps 8:** Click Close&Load.